# Как написать плагин для Bitrix24

Tags: javascript, html, css, битрикс24

Продукт извне, как создать плагин для Битрикс24 (сайты), чтобы интеграция продукта проходила автоматически, когда человек добавляет его на свой сайт. А также, чтобы в админке можно было менять какие-либо параметры интеграции (цвет, размер и прочие css стили).

Comment: Вы ожидаете полную инструкцию?) Это слишком размытый вопрос для SO.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar нет, просто в общих чертах)